# Error message: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

When executing my doDelete.php, this error message appears:

" Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyp`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `book_user_key` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) "

the Delete query:

```
$queryDelete = "DELETE FROM user  WHERE id = $theUserID";
```

the retrieve information query from 3 tables:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM user,country,book where book.id=user.id AND user.country_id=country.country_id ORDER BY  `user`.`id` ASC";
```

The Relationship between my 'book' and 'user' table is that a user is able to add a book. Hence, the user ID is placed in the book table to identify which user adds a book. However when I want to delete a user from my php, the above error message appeared. Here's a snippet of the retrieval of user ID to delete the user. How do I fix this?

```
<td><form method="post" action="doDelete.php"><input type="hidden" name="theUserID" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" /</form></td>
```

Here is the relevant tables

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `fyp` ;
USE `fyp` ;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fyp`.`country`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fyp`.`country` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fyp`.`country` (
`country_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fyp`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fyp`.`user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fyp`.`user` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`date_of_birth` DATE NOT NULL,
`country_id` INT NOT NULL,
`gender_id` INT NOT NULL,
`role_id` INT NOT NULL,
`last_login` TIMESTAMP NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `fk_user_country1_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
INDEX `fk_user_gender1_idx` (`gender_id` ASC),
INDEX `fk_user_role1_idx` (`role_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `user_country_key`
FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
REFERENCES `fyp`.`country` (`country_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `user_gender_key`
FOREIGN KEY (`gender_id`)
REFERENCES `fyp`.`gender` (`gender_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `user_role_key`
FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
REFERENCES `fyp`.`role` (`role_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fyp`.`book`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fyp`.`book` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fyp`.`book` (
`book_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`ISBN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`book_desc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`year_published` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`year_of_birth` YEAR NOT NULL,
`image` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`genre_id` INT NOT NULL,
`publisher_id` INT NOT NULL,
`user_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`),
 INDEX `fk_book_publishers1_idx` (`publisher_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_book_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_book_genre1_idx` (`genre_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `book_publishers_key`
 FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
 REFERENCES `fyp`.`publishers` (`publisher_id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `book_user_key`
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
 REFERENCES `fyp`.`user` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `book_genre_key`
 FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`)
 REFERENCES `fyp`.`genre` (`genre_id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have a constraint in book table, that does not let you delete a user as long as there are books added by that user:

```
CONSTRAINT `book_user_key`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `fyp`.`user` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

You can change it to

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

so that deleting the user will delete all their books too.

Or you can set the constraint to

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

and remove NOT NULL from book.user_id: this will keep the books of the deleted user, but set their user_id to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a user record because it has related records in *book* table. It is how foreign key constraint works. You created this constraint in this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `fyp`.`user` (`id`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

To solve this problem you can:

1. Delete records in *book* table for given user id before deleting a given user from *user* table. This will require executing 2 DELETE statements one by one.
2. Modify a foreign key and use `ON DELETE CASCADE`. It will cause that records in *book* table will be deleted together with related records in *user* table automatically.

I prefer solution 1 because it gives you more control. It is also less error prone because you have to always explicitly delete records from 2 tables. In the second case it is possible that you will accidentally delete a lot of data from your database.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you have 1 or more **user_id** (which you want to delete) data in **Book** table.

Since the **user_id** in **Book** table is a **FOREIGN KEY** to **id** in **User** Table, then any delete operation on **User** table will be restricted by the **Constraint** (*book_user_key*).

You can check whether the data is exist or not by using this query in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM fyp.book WHERE user_id = ***[UserIDWhichYouWantToDelete]***
```

So the next thing is, what are you going to do if you already have that "User" data in Book table?

*You can find more literature about **FOREIGN_KEY** on many website.*